# Narrow down php-sql connection failure to server settings?

Tags: php, sql, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect to a MYSQL database on server A from server B. The hosting company that we are working with, owns both server A and server B. This is my first attempt at an external DB connection.

I have written the following PHP code to try to connect to the MYSQL database on server A from server B. The code looks like most other code I have Googled in regards to connecting to external MYSQL databases..

```
$IPAddress_O_fServer_A = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX';
$Server_A_DB_Pass = 'P-WORD';
$Server_A_DB_User = 'U-NAME';
$con = mysql_connect($IPAddress_Of_Server_A, $Server_A_DB_User, $Server_A_DB_Pass);
```

Now when this code executes on Server B, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on   'XXX.XX.XX.XXX' (4) in /var/www/web12/web/dev/front-end.php on line 10
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on XXX.XX.XX.XXX' (4)
```

...where line 10 is the mysql_connect() call.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this code? 
If the connection is not working would it be safe to say that there must be an issue with either the servers external connection permissions or some other settings?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html (2) http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Does user U-NAME can connect to database when testing on localhost?

Comment: Probably is a secured server that don't accept connections outside of localhost...

Comment: Yes, the username/password is being used actively on server A with a localhost address in the mysql_connect()

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) and make sure that you're system is configured to allow remote access.

Secondly the user name "U-NAME" will actually be "U-NAME@localhost" and will have permissions set up as such. For example consider the following GRANT statement.

```
GRANT SELECT *
    ON foo.bar
    TO 'U-NAME'@'localhost'
```

The user name "U-NAME" has permission to select entries from the database foo, table bar, but it is exclusively localhost access. In order to allow remote you'd have to grant permissions similarly to the following.

```
GRANT SELECT *
    ON foo.bar
    TO 'U-NAME'@'xx.xx.xx.xx'
```